# Referenced Assemblies in Web Site

Tags: asp.net

Am I correct in assuming that I always need to explicitly deploy referenced assemblies when their source changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you do.  If you use the publish command in Visual Studios, it will include all the assemblies you need in the folder you selected to publish your site.

If a .dll has changed and you need to update your site, you can just publish again or copy the .dll.